# I want to add a new form input field using a smarty page with php

Tags: php, sql, input, smarty

I have a third party script and in this script I want to add a new input field in the *User profile update* -page. I want to save the **bank** field where user can save their bank names. I have already created a **bank** column in the database table **members**.

The script does not save the bank name to the database.

```
<form id="settingsform" onsubmit="return submitform(this.id);">
<input type="hidden" name="a" value="submit" />
<td align="right" width="50%">Bank Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="bank" id="bank" value="{$user_info.bank}"></td>
```

This is the code that I have for the form.

All settings are shown on the **.tpl** (*Smarty*) -file. Could you please help me out?

Comment: Can you please post the php part and one more thing are you getting other fields for the same form in the php to update in mysql?

Comment: veerendra SIR thanks for reply and i have post the TPL and PHP files code in this link you can check

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25479915/where-am-i-missing-to-put-a-new-filed-bank

Comment: Why you have posted 2 questions and one more thing i cant find any code to retrieve the field with the name bank in your php file

Comment: yes SIR that's i am saying that what code i will put in my php file to preform this act i mean to save bank value from user to sql ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the line

```
$bank = $input->pc['bank'];
```

to the code here

```
if ($_POST['a'] == "submit") {
        verifyajax();
        $email = $input->pc['email'];
        $bank = $input->pc['bank'];
```

I think You have not retrieved the bank field on the php file.

you need to get the posted bank value as you have retrieved the other fields