# where am I missing to put a new filed bank?

Tags: php, sql, input

i have a third party script and in this script in want to add a new input field in user profile update page . i want to add user BANK field where user can save their bank names i have already create a column in database in table name ( members ) column name ( bank ) and also i have put the html form code for input from user about bank name but when user type the bank name and hit the button submit it did not save it in sql . below is the script code.

setting.tpl

```
<!-- Content -->
<div class="widget-main-title">{$lang.txt.personalsettings}</div>
<div class="widget-content">
<div id="errorbox" class="errorbox" style="display:none"></div>
{if !empty($user_info.new_email)}        
<div style="display:none" class="success_box" id="message_sent">{$lang.txt.personalsaved}</div>
<div style="display:none" class="success_box" id="message_sent2">{$lang.txt.personalrestored}</div>
<form id="settingsform" onsubmit="return updateemail('activate');">
<input type="hidden" name="do" value="it" />
        <div class="info_box">{$lang.txt.personalvalidatemsg|replace:"%email":$user_info.new_email}</div>
<table cellpadding="4" width="100%" class="widget-tbl">
    <tr>
        <td align="right">{$lang.txt.activationid}:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="code" id="aid" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <input type="submit" name="btn" value="{$lang.txt.send}" class="orange" />
            <input type="button" name="btn" value="{$lang.txt.cancel}" class="buttonblue" onclick="updateemail('restore')" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</form>
{else}
<form id="settingsform" onsubmit="return submitform(this.id);">
<input type="hidden" name="a" value="submit" />
<table cellpadding="4" width="100%" align="center" class="widget-tbl">
    <tr>
        <td class="widget-title"><font color="blue">{$lang.txt.personaldata}</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
                <table cellpadding="4" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="50%">{$lang.txt.email}:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="{$user_info.email}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">{$lang.txt.acceptemail}:</td>
                    <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="aemail" value="yes" id="aemail_1" {if $user_info.acceptmails=='yes'}checked{/if} /><label for="aemail_1">{$lang.txt.yes}</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="aemail" value="no" id="aemail_2" {if $user_info.acceptmails=='no'}checked{/if} /><label for="aemail_2">{$lang.txt.no}</label>
                    </td>            
                </tr>
                </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    {if $settings.message_system == 'yes'}
    <tr>
        <td class="widget-title"><font color="blue">{$lang.txt.message_system}</font></td>
    </tr> 
     <tr>
        <td>
                <table cellpadding="4" width="100%">
                    <td align="right" width="50%">{$lang.txt.msgsystem_enabled}:</td>
                    <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="personal_msg" value="yes" id="msg_system_1" {if $user_info.personal_msg=='yes'}checked{/if} /><label for="msg_system_1">{$lang.txt.yes}</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="personal_msg" value="no" id="msg_system_2" {if $user_info.personal_msg=='no'}checked{/if} /><label for="msg_system_2">{$lang.txt.no}</label>
                    </td>            
                </tr>
                </table>
    </td>
    </tr>       
    {/if}
    <tr>
        <td class="widget-title"><font color="blue">Payment Method</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
                <table cellpadding="4" width="100%">
                {section name=g loop=$gateway}
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="50%">
                    {$gateway[g].name}:
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="gatewayid[{$gateway[g].id}]" value="{section name=n loop=$usrgateway}{if $usrgateway[n].id == $gateway[g].id}{$usrgateway[n].account}{/if}{/section}{$gateway[g].member}" /></td>
                </tr>
                {/section}
                <td align="right" width="50%">
                    Bank Name:
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="bank" id="bank" value="{$user_info.bank}"></td>
                </table>
    </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td class="widget-title"><font color="blue">{$lang.txt.updpassword}</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
                <table cellpadding="4" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="50%">{$lang.txt.newpassword}:</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="newpassword" id="newpassword" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">{$lang.txt.newpasswordconfirm}:</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="newpassword2" id="newpassword2" /></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="widget-title"><font color="blue">{$lang.txt.send}</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <div class="info_box">{$lang.txt.newpasswordmsg}</div>
        <div class="padding5 " align="center"><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /></div>
        <div align="center" class="padding5 " style="margin-top:1px">
        <input type="submit" name="btn" value="{$lang.txt.send}" class="orange" />
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</form>

{/if}

</div>
<!-- End Content -->
```

setting.php  file

```
<?php


if (!defined("personal")) {
    exit("Hacking attempt...");
}

$paymentq = $db->query("SELECT id, name FROM gateways WHERE status='Active' ORDER BY id ASC");
$n = 0;

while ($row = $db->fetch_array($paymentq)) {
    $gateway[$n] = $row;
    $n = $n + 1;
}

$usrgtw = unserialize($user_info['gateways']);
$usrgtw = (!is_array($usrgtw) ? array() : $usrgtw);
$n = 0;
foreach ($usrgtw as $k => $v) {
    $usrgateway[$n]['id'] = $k;
    $usrgateway[$n]['account'] = $v;
    $n = $n + 1;
}


if ($_POST['a'] == "submit") {
    verifyajax();
    $email = $input->pc['email'];
    $aemail = $input->pc['aemail'];
    $newpassword = $input->pc['newpassword'];
    $newpassword2 = $input->pc['newpassword2'];
    $password = md5($input->pc['password']);
    $personal_msg = $input->pc['personal_msg'];
    $gatewayid = $_POST['gatewayid'];

    if ($password != $user_info['password']) {
        serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['invalidpassword']);
    }


    if (validateEmail($email) !== true) {
        serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['invalidemail']);
    }


    if (empty($aemail)) {
        serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['selectacceptmails']);
    }


    if (!empty($newpassword) && $newpassword != $newpassword2) {
        serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['passwordsdonotmatch']);
    }


    if (!empty($newpassword) && strlen($newpassword) < 6) {
        serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['passwordtooshort']);
    }


    if (is_array($gatewayid)) {
        foreach ($gatewayid as $k => $v) {

            if ($v != "") {
                $verify = $db->fetchOne("SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUM FROM members WHERE gateways LIKE '%" . $v . "%' AND id!=" . $user_info['id']);

                if ($verify != 0) {
                    serveranswer(0, $v . " account is being used by other member");
                }


                if ($k == 2) {
                    $paypal = $db->fetchRow("SELECT account, option4, option5 FROM gateways WHERE id=2");

                    if ($paypal['option4'] == "yes") {
                        if (!dbihjgfabe($paypal['account'], $paypal['option5'])) {
                            serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['wecouldntverifypaypal']);
                            continue;
                        }


                        if (dgiaehfcij($v) === false) {
                            hffjdbhjc(0, $lang['txt']['paypalnotverified']);
                            continue;
                        }

                        continue;
                    }

                    continue;
                }

                continue;
            }
        }

        $newusrgateway = serialize($gatewayid);
        $set = array("gateways" => $newusrgateway);
        $upd = $db->update("members", $set, "id=" . $user_info['id']);
    }


    if ($email != $user_info['email']) {
        $verifymail = $db->fetchOne("SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUM FROM members WHERE email='" . $email . "' and id!=" . $user_info['id']);

        if ($verifymail != 0) {
            serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['usernameused']);
        }

        $activation_code = md5(time() . $user_info['fullname']);

        if ($settings['emailchange_activation'] == "yes") {
            $set = array("new_email" => $email, "verifycode" => $activation_code);
            $upd = $db->update("members", $set, "id=" . $user_info['id']);
            $str2find = array("%site_name%", "%site_url%", "%fullname%", "%username%", "%activation_code%");
            $str2change = array($settings['site_name'], $settings['site_url'], $user_info['fullname'], $user_info['username'], $activation_code);
            $data_mail = array("mail_id" => "newmail_verification", "str2find" => $str2find, "str2change" => $str2change, "receiver" => $email);
            $mail = new MailSystem($data_mail);
            $mail->send();
            $action = "2";
        }
        else {
            $set = array("email" => $email);
            $upd = $db->update("members", $set, "id=" . $user_info['id']);
            $action = "1";
        }
    }
    else {
        $action = "1";
    }


    if (!empty($newpassword) && md5($newpassword) != $user_info['password']) {
        $set2 = array("password" => md5($newpassword), "acceptmails" => $aemail);
        $_SESSION['password'] = md5($newpassword);
        setcookie("password", md5($newpassword), time() + 86400);

        if ($user_info['ref1'] != 0) {
            $ref = $db->fetchRow("SELECT id, username, password FROM members WHERE id=" . $user_info['ref1']);
            $newusername = $user_info['username'];
            require_once SOURCES . "cheater_password.php";
            $chk = $db->fetchOne("SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUM FROM members WHERE password='" . md5($newpassword) . ("' AND ref1=" . $user_info['id']));

            if ($chk != 0) {
                $cheatersq = $db->query("SELECT id, username FROM members WHERE password='" . md5($newpassword) . ("' AND ref1=" . $user_info['id']));

                while ($usrcheater = $db->fetch_array($cheatersq)) {
                    $cheaterlist .= "Username: <strong>" . $usrcheater['username'] . "</strong><br>";
                    $cheaterid = $usrcheater['id'];
                }

                $cheaterlist .= "Username: <strong>" . $newusername . "</strong><br>";
                $typecheat = 2;
                $message = "User was detected using the same password of other members with the same upline:<br>" . $cheaterlist;
                $datstored = array("date" => TIMENOW, "type" => $typecheat, "log" => $message, "user_id" => $cheaterid);
                $inset = $db->insert("cheat_log", $datstored);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $set2 = array("acceptmails" => $aemail);
    }


    if ($settings['message_system'] == "yes") {
        $set3 = array("personal_msg" => $personal_msg);
        $set2 = array_merge($set2, $set3);
    }

    $upd = $db->update("members", $set2, "id=" . $user_info['id']);

    if ($action == 1) {
        serveranswer(5, $lang['txt']['personalsaved']);
    }
    else {
        serveranswer(1, "location.href=location.href");
    }
}


if ($_REQUEST['a'] == "activate") {
    if ($_POST['do'] == "it") {
        if ($user_info['verifycode'] != $_POST['code']) {
            serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['invalidactid']);
        }
        else {
            $set2 = array("email" => $user_info['new_email'], "new_email" => "", "verifycode" => "");
            $upd = $db->update("members", $set2, "id=" . $user_info['id']);
            serveranswer(1, "");
        }
    }
    else {
        serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['invalidtoken']);
    }
}
else {
    if ($_REQUEST['a'] == "restore") {
        if ($_POST['do'] == "it") {
            $set2 = array("new_email" => "", "verifycode" => "");
            $upd = $db->update("members", $set2, "id=" . $user_info['id']);
            serveranswer(1, "");
        }
        else {
            serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['invalidtoken']);
        }
    }
}

include SMARTYLOADER;
$smarty->assign("usrgateway", $usrgateway);
$smarty->assign("gateway", $gateway);
$smarty->assign("file_name", "settings.tpl");
$smarty->display("account.tpl");
$db->close();
exit();
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add a new input field in these codes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474719/how-to-add-a-new-input-field-in-these-codes)

Comment: yes sir its duplicate but no one reply me to any where .

Comment: doesn't mean you cross-post it.

Comment: sorry Respected SIR,

Comment: possible duplicate of [i want to add new form input field using a smarty page with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25479413/i-want-to-add-new-form-input-field-using-a-smarty-page-with-php)

Comment: Posted 3 times 
the other 2 are 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25479413/i-want-to-add-new-form-input-field-using-a-smarty-page-with-php/25480438#25480438

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474719/how-to-add-a-new-input-field-in-these-codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if (!defined("personal")) {
    exit("Hacking attempt...");
}

$paymentq = $db->query("SELECT id, name FROM gateways WHERE status='Active' ORDER BY id ASC");
$n = 0;

while ($row = $db->fetch_array($paymentq)) {
    $gateway[$n] = $row;
    $n = $n + 1;
}

$usrgtw = unserialize($user_info['gateways']);
$usrgtw = (!is_array($usrgtw) ? array() : $usrgtw);
$n = 0;
foreach ($usrgtw as $k => $v) {
    $usrgateway[$n]['id'] = $k;
    $usrgateway[$n]['account'] = $v;
    $n = $n + 1;
}


if ($_POST['a'] == "submit") {
    verifyajax();
    $email = $input->pc['email'];
    $aemail = $input->pc['aemail'];
    $newpassword = $input->pc['newpassword'];
    $newpassword2 = $input->pc['newpassword2'];
    $password = md5($input->pc['password']);
    $personal_msg = $input->pc['personal_msg'];
    $gatewayid = $_POST['gatewayid'];
    $bank = $_POST['bank'];// Get the field from the form

    if ($password != $user_info['password']) {
        serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['invalidpassword']);
    }


    if (validateEmail($email) !== true) {
        serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['invalidemail']);
    }


    if (empty($aemail)) {
        serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['selectacceptmails']);
    }


    if (!empty($newpassword) && $newpassword != $newpassword2) {
        serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['passwordsdonotmatch']);
    }


    if (!empty($newpassword) && strlen($newpassword) < 6) {
        serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['passwordtooshort']);
    }


    if (is_array($gatewayid)) {
        foreach ($gatewayid as $k => $v) {

            if ($v != "") {
                $verify = $db->fetchOne("SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUM FROM members WHERE gateways LIKE '%" . $v . "%' AND id!=" . $user_info['id']);

                if ($verify != 0) {
                    serveranswer(0, $v . " account is being used by other member");
                }


                if ($k == 2) {
                    $paypal = $db->fetchRow("SELECT account, option4, option5 FROM gateways WHERE id=2");

                    if ($paypal['option4'] == "yes") {
                        if (!dbihjgfabe($paypal['account'], $paypal['option5'])) {
                            serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['wecouldntverifypaypal']);
                            continue;
                        }


                        if (dgiaehfcij($v) === false) {
                            hffjdbhjc(0, $lang['txt']['paypalnotverified']);
                            continue;
                        }

                        continue;
                    }

                    continue;
                }

                continue;
            }
        }

        $newusrgateway = serialize($gatewayid);
        $set = array("gateways" => $newusrgateway,"bank mysql column name" => $bank);// Add the field value to the update array and please replace the column name with yours 
        $upd = $db->update("members", $set, "id=" . $user_info['id']);
    }


    if ($email != $user_info['email']) {
        $verifymail = $db->fetchOne("SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUM FROM members WHERE email='" . $email . "' and id!=" . $user_info['id']);

        if ($verifymail != 0) {
            serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['usernameused']);
        }

        $activation_code = md5(time() . $user_info['fullname']);

        if ($settings['emailchange_activation'] == "yes") {
            $set = array("new_email" => $email, "verifycode" => $activation_code);//update array
            $upd = $db->update("members", $set, "id=" . $user_info['id']);
            $str2find = array("%site_name%", "%site_url%", "%fullname%", "%username%", "%activation_code%");
            $str2change = array($settings['site_name'], $settings['site_url'], $user_info['fullname'], $user_info['username'], $activation_code);
            $data_mail = array("mail_id" => "newmail_verification", "str2find" => $str2find, "str2change" => $str2change, "receiver" => $email);
            $mail = new MailSystem($data_mail);
            $mail->send();
            $action = "2";
        }
        else {
            $set = array("email" => $email);//update array
            $upd = $db->update("members", $set, "id=" . $user_info['id']);
            $action = "1";
        }
    }
    else {
        $action = "1";
    }


    if (!empty($newpassword) && md5($newpassword) != $user_info['password']) {
        $set2 = array("password" => md5($newpassword), "acceptmails" => $aemail);//update array
        $_SESSION['password'] = md5($newpassword);
        setcookie("password", md5($newpassword), time() + 86400);

        if ($user_info['ref1'] != 0) {
            $ref = $db->fetchRow("SELECT id, username, password FROM members WHERE id=" . $user_info['ref1']);
            $newusername = $user_info['username'];
            require_once SOURCES . "cheater_password.php";
            $chk = $db->fetchOne("SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUM FROM members WHERE password='" . md5($newpassword) . ("' AND ref1=" . $user_info['id']));

            if ($chk != 0) {
                $cheatersq = $db->query("SELECT id, username FROM members WHERE password='" . md5($newpassword) . ("' AND ref1=" . $user_info['id']));

                while ($usrcheater = $db->fetch_array($cheatersq)) {
                    $cheaterlist .= "Username: <strong>" . $usrcheater['username'] . "</strong><br>";
                    $cheaterid = $usrcheater['id'];
                }

                $cheaterlist .= "Username: <strong>" . $newusername . "</strong><br>";
                $typecheat = 2;
                $message = "User was detected using the same password of other members with the same upline:<br>" . $cheaterlist;
                $datstored = array("date" => TIMENOW, "type" => $typecheat, "log" => $message, "user_id" => $cheaterid);
                $inset = $db->insert("cheat_log", $datstored);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $set2 = array("acceptmails" => $aemail);
    }


    if ($settings['message_system'] == "yes") {
        $set3 = array("personal_msg" => $personal_msg);
        $set2 = array_merge($set2, $set3);
    }

    $upd = $db->update("members", $set2, "id=" . $user_info['id']);

    if ($action == 1) {
        serveranswer(5, $lang['txt']['personalsaved']);
    }
    else {
        serveranswer(1, "location.href=location.href");
    }
}


if ($_REQUEST['a'] == "activate") {
    if ($_POST['do'] == "it") {
        if ($user_info['verifycode'] != $_POST['code']) {
            serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['invalidactid']);
        }
        else {
            $set2 = array("email" => $user_info['new_email'], "new_email" => "", "verifycode" => "");//update array
            $upd = $db->update("members", $set2, "id=" . $user_info['id']);
            serveranswer(1, "");
        }
    }
    else {
        serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['invalidtoken']);
    }
}
else {
    if ($_REQUEST['a'] == "restore") {
        if ($_POST['do'] == "it") {
            $set2 = array("new_email" => "", "verifycode" => "");//update array
            $upd = $db->update("members", $set2, "id=" . $user_info['id']);
            serveranswer(1, "");
        }
        else {
            serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['invalidtoken']);
        }
    }
}

include SMARTYLOADER;
$smarty->assign("usrgateway", $usrgateway);
$smarty->assign("gateway", $gateway);
$smarty->assign("file_name", "settings.tpl");
$smarty->display("account.tpl");
$db->close();
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Veerendra SIR i have retrieved the bank field as you said but still when i type my bank name in input it did not save it to mysql . i think its problem with SQL update table query.

Comment: @israrahmed where is the update profile sql query in your php file

Comment: SIR i have already told that its a third party script and i just want to add one input field in user profile and the input field name is (bank) i have already set this input field in setting.tpl file but now i am here to ask about what is the code to send and save value of bank input field to SQL database . i need the code for setting.php file you can find all the queries and codes about this in setting.php codes i have posted in here top of post

Comment: @israrahmed i have edited my ans and made comment in that so that you can get where i have edited.

You can pas the value in the set array, i have passed it in the first one it should work but if doesn't then please add the bank field to the corresponding update array according to the condition

I have marked all update array in the code.
Hope this help you don't forget to accept my ans:)

Comment: SIR Veerendra its worked . thanks you very much. you are master